# Reading a Value of in an Input Box and Assign it in a Variable for Encryption and Decryption

Tags: php, encryption

I am trying to create a security feature for my log-in form wherein passwords are converted into hash codes the moment a new password is saved or a new user is added, which will be saved in the password field in the database. In every log-in of the user, the password will be decrypted to be read by the system.

I've started with these codes I get from my search but I can't access the value in the input box:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


            <form method="post" action="">

                        <input type="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter email"  /> <br>

                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />

                <button type="submit" name="submit">LOG IN</button>
            </form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username = (isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '');
$password = (isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '');

$encrypted = encryptIt( $password );
$decrypted = decryptIt( $encrypted );

echo $encrypted . '<br />' . $decrypted;

function encryptIt( $q ) {
$cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
$qEncoded      = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
return( $qEncoded );
}

function decryptIt( $q ) {
$cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
$qDecoded      = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
return( $qDecoded );
}
}
?>
```

It's saying:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function encryptIt() in C:\xampp\Xampp\htdocs\subukan.php on line 23.

Comment: In case of `if` functions should be defined __before__ usage.

Comment: Do not Decrypt!!, just salt/hash all passwords (EG SHA256), then hash any pasword entry in the login form and compare this with the hashed version of the password. Password ENCRYPTION is a very bad and very unsecure habit. Password HASHiNG is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we get to deep into this, lets stop and really think about what is being attempted: you're attempting to single-handedly reinvent a very complex wheel that has had millions of hours of high level professional effort towards a secure and industry support solution.

1) Creating your own encryption process (unless you're a mathematics or computer science professional) is placing **every single one** of you users at risk. Instead, refer to the encryption packages available from symphony, Laravel, Yii, etc.

2) If you are a mathematics or computer science professional please refer to scholastic papers that have been published on the topic of encryption algorithms.